# How to manage i18n properties files in eclipse rcp?

Tags: java, properties, internationalization, eclipse-rcp

The translated Strings in Eclipse RCP are stored in *.properties files, which look as following:

```
//these keys are used in...
key1=translation
key2=translation

//these keys are used in another place...
key11=translation
key12=translation
....
```

Now there may be quite many strings.
It is usual to separate the strings into groups, using string's semantics. 
E.g. strings for toolbar are goruped together.

Now those groups grow, sometimes the rows are swaped.
If such a *properties file was extended in english, and now the Strings which are new should be translated into spanish *properties too.

The problem is, that is hard to find the strings, which were added into the main *properties and now should be added to the spanish file too.
What is the usual appoach to manage such *properties files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On our projects, we use the [Resource Bundle Editor plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-resourcebundle-editor).  It allows you to edit all your properties files at once in a single window.  Couldn't be easier.